# MacOS OmniSharp and vscode timeout errror

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

This morning I started vscode(1.13.1) and want to write code in C# (dotnet core). But I got the same error, which you can find in google, but in current version of OmniSharp. Omnisharp correctly see my project, but didn't start. In OmniaSharp log is this:

```
OmniSharp server started wth Mono
Path: /Users/petrtomasek/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.10.0/bin/run
PID: 1351

OmniSharp: -s /Users/petrtomasek/Projects/CestujnakoleNew --hostPID 1267 --stdio DotNet:enablePackageRestore=false --encoding utf-8 --loglevel information formattingOptions:useTabs=false formattingOptions:tabSize=4 formattingOptions:indentationSize=4
{"Event":"log","Body":{"LogLevel":"INFORMATION","Name":"OmniSharp.Startup","Message":"Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/CestujnakoleNew' on host 1267."},"Seq":1,"Type":"event"}
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Initializing in /Users/petrtomasek/Projects/CestujnakoleNew
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Auto package restore: False
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Update workspace context
[info]: OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem
        Resolving projects references
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to /Users/petrtomasek/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.10.0/bin/omnisharp/msbuild/MSBuild.dll
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
        MSBuildExtensionsPath environment variable set to /Users/petrtomasek/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.10.0/bin/omnisharp/msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
        MSBuild will use local OmniSharp installation.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/Users/petrtomasek/Projects/CestujnakoleNew'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
        Loading project: /Users/petrtomasek/Projects/CestujnakoleNew/CestujnakoleNew.csproj
Discovered Mono file path: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono
Resolved symbolic link for Mono file path: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/bin/mono-sgen64
[ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).
```

I tried restart mac, reinstall vscode, omnisharp and now upgrade to 5.2. preview version. Nothing helped. Still the same error. Intellisense, go to definition etc. doesn't work as well.

Is there something I can still try to do?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**

Version of c# extension for vscode is the newest(1.10.0)

Comment: Ok, here is solutions: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1585

Answer (score 3):

Update your user setting or workspace settings with the below line of code

```
{
  "omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout": 600
}
```

Any number other than the default **60** should be fine.

Comment: I slowly went with omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout upto 1200 and still the omnisharp failed to load because of time-out issue. But, I found the root-cause of that delay. Kindly check my above answer. If we exclude the node_modules, other javascript and static file folders in the DefaultExcludes section, then it loading in couple of seconds. No need for increasing the time-out.

Comment: Setting to 600 wrked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this delay is due to the vast content of library files included in the **wwwroot** folder which is actually neither required by the OmniSharp nor the C# compiler.

I just added these lines given below in to the **.csproj** file, as mentioned in the thread but with respect to my folder structure and this thing pushed the loading of OmniSharp loading process in couple of seconds upwards,

```
<PropertyGroup
     <DefaultItemExcludes>wwwroot/global/**;$(DefaultItemExcludes)</DefaultItemExcludes> 
     <DefaultItemExcludes>wwwroot/vendors/**;$(DefaultItemExcludes)</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And ofcourse please go ahead and modify replace the **wwwroot/vendors/** and **wwwroot/global/** with as many as folders you want for your application's static files folder structure which doesn't required to be compiled by the C# Compiler. Another advantage of adding these lines in csproj file is, it boosts up the performance of the build cycles during the development!,

I have actually asked this in the following Link:

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1585

And got answer from a reference from this Link:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7525

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking Omnisharp:Wait For Debugger setting made it work for me.