# Omnisharp server load timed out, mac os, vs code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, omnisharp

I am getting the error

`[ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).`

whenever I try to restart omnisharp server. Unfortunately this is all provided omnisharp output. It started after I migrated my project to dotnet 6.0. I've already tried to set DefaultItemExcludes for all web related directories, I've increased timeout to 20 minutes, I've restarted and installed C# extension and vs code many times. Nothing of that helped me.

This is happening even with the simplest generated project using `dotnet new web` command. I assume it is not a project related issue.

My omnisharp settings is

```
"omnisharp.enableImportCompletion": true,
"omnisharp.useModernNet": true,
"omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout": 1200,
"omnisharp.dotnetPath": "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101",
"omnisharp.monoPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/",
```

I use

- mac os 12.3.1
- vs code 1.68.1
- c# extension 1.25.0
- dotnet 6.0.106
- mono 6.12.0.182

This thread does not fix my issue as I mentioned above I've tried all suggested solutions. It seams to me my problem is somehow connected with the new version of dotnet 6.0 and the new omnisharp approach.

[MacOS OmniSharp and vscode timeout errror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698658/macos-omnisharp-and-vscode-timeout-errror)

Thank you for any advice.